# How to remove part of the URL within window.location?

Tags: javascript, window.location

I have fetched `window.location` into a variable. Now, I want to remove part of the string from the href within the location object, but still retain the object.

In other words, I want to modify the location object, and still be able to use `window.location.protocol` and `window.location.host`, but those functions need to work on the modified object.

For example, something like this where my browser displays `"https://my.domain.org/site"`:

```
var thisloc = window.location;
Modify the href within that object to "http://my.domain.org/othersite"

//now I want it to fetch "http" instead of "https" based on my modified object
var thisprot = thisloc.protocol;
```

Will that work? If it does, it would be very nice. Otherwise, I have to parse the URL to get the protocol, host and pathname from a modified href, which would also accomplish the same goal.

Comment: I disagree with the move to close this question. The asker is trying to find out a way of manipulating parts of a URL without messing with the window.location object. This post describes the general method for achieving this: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/parsing-urls-with-the-dom/

Comment: Thanks for the help! If I knew how to ask the question better, I would.  It would be nice if folks would help get the questions asked better instead of blasting them.  I didn't want to parse the url; instead I wanted a way of manipulating the location object, and then reading from it after it was changed.  I looked at your link, and if you propose that as an answer, I will change my acceptance.

Comment: Done. Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by James Padosley's post on [Parsing URLs with the DOM!](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/parsing-urls-with-the-dom/), the trick here is to use an anchor element (`<a>`) as a URL builder/parser. With any anchor element, if you set its `href` property to some URL, it will be parsed by the DOM. Thereafter, you can freely modify the parts of that URL via properties on the anchor element. Query the `href` property at any time to see the full URL.

Using the example from the question…

```
var builder = document.createElement("a");

builder.href = "https://my.domain.org/site";
builder.protocol = "http://";
builder.pathname = "/othersite";

console.log(builder.href); // http://my.domain.org/othersite
```

At this point the anchor element's href will now be `http://my.domain.org/othersite`, as requested. Here's a JS Bin demonstrating it in action: http://jsbin.com/omoqen/1/edit.

The beauty is that anchor elements have the same URL component properties as the [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) object:

```
protocol
host
hostname
port
pathname
search
hash
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. Calo.  That is a very nice explanation of how to do the "impossible".  +1, solved.

Answer (score -1):

These are browser properties - you can fetch and modify the values, but referring to the property won't work in the way you describe.

Comment: Wow, you guys answer fast! I figured that it wouldn't work the way I wanted;  I suppose I'll have to parse them.  Oh well.